# Why css transform properties are not separate css properties?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Why was decided to add all transform properties to one css property?

Instead of:

```
.element {
    transform: translateX(50%) rotateZ(45deg) scale(0.8);
}
```

could be written:

```
.element {
    translate-x: 50%;
    rotate-z: 45deg;
    scale: 0.8;
}
```

Why was chosen first variant? Is this somehow connected with transformation matrix? Or prefixes?

When you write `media queries` for example, you need to copy the entire `transform` property (not DRY), in other case, it will be overwritten. The same problem when creating transitions, toggling states, etc... That's really uncomfortable.

An explanation of what is happening behind the scene is welcome.

Comment: The second variant does not exist. It's simply wrong.

Comment: @pol i know, I presented an example of how it could be easier.

Comment: CSS Level 4 has a proposal to make these all individual properties. As for why they weren't from the outset, you'd have to ask the W3C.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not just a set of properties, it's a list, where the transformations are applied in order, and a single transform type can occur more than once in the list.

So you can for example do:

```css
div {
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.one {
  background-color:red;
  transform:translate(50%,5%) scale(0.5)
    rotate(45deg) translate(50px,10px)
}
.two {
  background-color:blue;
  transform:scale(0.5) translate(50%,5%)
    rotate(45deg) translate(50px,10px)
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

And you can see that the X-position of the diamond is affected by the order in which the transforms are applied.